# Upload file to server with NodeJS and express-fileupload and directly stream it to Azure cloud

Tags: node.js, azure, express, file-upload

I want to upload files to my Azure Blob storage via NodeJS. Until now I upload the files to my server via `express-fileupload`, they are stored on its disk and then they are uploaded to the Azure blob storage. Now I want to upload the files to Azure while I upload them, i.e. not save them on the server disk before uploading them to Azure. This is the method I use until now:

```
router.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    "use strict"
    if (!req.files)
        return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');

    // The name of the input field (i.e. "sampleFile") is used to retrieve the uploaded file
    let context = req.files.context;
let filenameContext = req.files.context.name;

    context.mv('../'+filenameContext, function(err) {
    if (err)
        return res.status(500).send(err);
    else {
        blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromStream(containerName, filenameContext, context, function(error, result, response){
            if(!error){
                console.log(filenameContext+" stored in blob");
                fs.unlink('../'+filenameContext, function() {
                    if (err) throw err;
                });
            } else {
                console.error(filenameContext+" storing in blob failed");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Any way to turn the uploaded file directly into a stream to use the `createBlockBlobFromStream` method without storing the file on the server disk first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using [`createBlockBlobFromText`](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/BlobService.html#createBlockBlobFromText__anchor) instead:

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    if (!req.files)
        return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.'); 

    let data = req.files.context.data;
    let filename = req.files.context.name;    

    blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromText(containerName, filename, data, function(err) {
        if (err)
            return res.status(500).send(err);

        res.send('File uploaded!');
    })
})
```

Comment: Beautiful, simple answer; everything I need, THANK YOU